# php mysql search, highlight part of result that contains provided keywords

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

For testing purposes I've stored in database name of colors which are:

```
Apple green
Banana yellow
Brick red
Charcoal
Coffee
```

And I created functions to search and display results with using `$_GET` and address bar, so far it all works perfectly. So for example if I type to the search form this: `ap le ee`

My address bar looks like this:

`http://test.com/file.php?keywords=ap+le+ee`

and my result is obviously `Apple green`

If I type this: `c o` or `co`

My result is: `Charcoal` and `Coffee`

At this point I want to upgrade this search engine and highlight in result only those parts that matches with provided keywords so what I want to achieve is this:

If I type: `app ee`

I want to have in result something like this: `<strong>App</strong>le gr<strong>ee</strong>n`

and I don't have any idea how to achieve it.

I call my results like this:

```
$colors = get_colors(isset($_GET['keywords']) ? $_GET['keywords'] : null);
foreach($colors as $color) {
    echo $color['color_name'] . '<br />';
}
```

If anyone could help me do it, I'll be very grateful, thank you in advance :)

**---EDIT--- 10.03.2014 08:34**

This is now the code im using:

```
$colors = get_colors(isset($_GET['keywords']) ? $_GET['keywords'] : null);
foreach($colors as $color) {
    $output = $color['color_name'];

    foreach (explode(' ', $_GET['keywords']) as $term)
        $output = preg_replace('/(?![^<>]*>)'.preg_quote($term,"/").'/i', '<span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $output);

    echo $output . "<br />";
}
```

Things that work perfect (testing case `Banana yellow`, `Charcoal`):

1. doesnt matter if i type `l o` or `o l` both of those will highlight properly in testing cases.
2. script doesnt fail if i type last letter, i can type `ban w` and it will properly return highlighted `Banana yellow`.

The only thing that doesnt work in it is:

1. if i type `bana nana` it highlights only `bana` in `Banana yellow`

So i believe that right now im looking for solution for overlaping terms to work together that if i type `bri ick` it should highlight all `Brick` in `Brick red` instead of only `Bri`.

Anyone with ideas how to sort that?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please have a try.

Comment: Ive tried it, well, there are 2 major problems with that script, at first if you got color like `Fire red` and you type `r` it wont do anything cos you need to provide at least 2 characters wich is bad for me, next if i type `re` or `r e` or `e r` it will always highlight only one `re` in `Fire`, `red` will remain unhighlighted.

Comment: Ok, see edit of my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay i needed to test it under various conditions, this is seriously a masterpiece, you've done something huge for me, thank you for this, it works in every single way, this is solution i was in need of :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @Utkanos suggestion:

```
foreach($colors as $color) {
    $output = $color['color_name'];
    foreach(explode(' ', $_GET['keywords']) as $term)
        $output = preg_replace('/('.$term.')(?![^>]*>)/i', '<strong>$1</strong>', $output);
    echo  $output .'<br />';
}
```

You want the result from the `preg_match` to replace the `$term`.

Sorry, it's a lot of code for a apparently "simply" problem, but this should do, what you expect:

```
$colors = array("Apple green",
                "Banana yellow",
                "Brick red",
                "Charcoal",
                "Coffee",
                "Fire red");

$terms = "re e";
$output = "";

foreach($colors as $color) {
    $output = $color;
    $words = array();

    foreach(explode(' ', $terms) as $term) {
        $match = preg_match_all("/(". $term .")/i", $output, $hits, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        if($match) {
            $positions = array();
            foreach($hits[1] as $hit) {

                for($i = $hit[1]; $i < strlen($hit[0]) + $hit[1]; $i++) {
                    $positions[] = $i;
                }
                $words[] = array($hits[0][0][0], $positions);

            }
        }
    }

    $positions = array();
    foreach($words as $word) {
        foreach($word[1] as $position)
            $positions[] = $position;
    }

    $positions = array_unique($positions);
    asort($positions);
    $positions = array_values($positions);

    if(count($positions) > 0) {
        $offset = 0;
        $open = false;
        $closed = true;

        $i = $positions[0];
        foreach($positions as $value) {

            if($value != $i AND !$closed) {
                $output = substr_replace($output, "</strong>", $i + $offset, 0);
                $offset += 9;
                $open = false;
                $closed = true;
                $i = $value;
            }

            if(!$open AND $closed) {
                $output = substr_replace($output, "<strong>", $value + $offset, 0);
                $offset += 8;
                $open = true;
                $closed = false;
            }

            $i++;

        }

        if(!$closed)
            $output = substr_replace($output, "</strong>", $positions[count($positions)-1] + $offset +1, 0);
    }


    echo $output ."<br/>";

}
```

Comment: I know you will probably hate me for being such pain in this ass;d but i got last problem, script is working properly it does highlight stuff without altering it which is awesome. The problem is if someone will type keywords backwards like "yell ban" it will return "Banana yellow" as it should but it only highlight "yell", "ban" will be skipped. Is there any simple way to make it work in both ways ;)?

Comment: Shorten the regex to just `/('.$term.')/i` but note, that overlapping search terms will only highlight one result.

Comment: I changed regex and tested it for a min and it appears to be working, now doesnt matter what i type it will still give proper result and proper highlight, could you give example of situation that you described which script may fail beacuse of that shortened regex?

Comment: Search for "bana" and "nana".

Comment: well after hour of testing i figured out that shortening regex may break and cause errors additionally to problem with highlighting one result with overlapping terms. i had to change back to full regex which works and doesnt fail, but it also wont highlight if you type backwards, is there really no solution for this?

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/('.$term.')([^<]*)/i', '<strong>$1</strong>$2', $output)`

Comment: This one helped a lot with backward highlight, it works great, however in some situations it will break. If i type "bana n" it will break and produce "ng>Banang>na yellow" this is major problem right now, additionaly if i type mentioned above "bana nana" it will highlight only bana, good thing is you solved backward highlight though :)

Comment: Please update your question and clarify, how those overlapping and nested search terms should be handled.

Comment: i have edited my question, please see edit part, maybe you can think of something.

Answer (score 3):

By the look of it you're allowing multiple search terms, separated by space. So I'd loop over the terms and do a replace on the colour before output.

```
foreach($colors as $color) {
    $output = $color['color_name'];
    foreach(explode(' ', $_GET['keywords']) as $term)
        $output = preg_replace('/'.$term.'(?![^>]*>)/i', '<strong>'.$term.'</strong>', $output);
    echo  preg_replace('/And\b/', 'and', ucwords($output)).'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick respond mate:)
your solution is nearly perfect but produces some errors
if i type "App ee" it will return "Apple green" with higlighted letters perfectly but if i provide for search "App n" it will be in result this:
"ng>Appng>le green", 
it breakes also in some other situations, any idea how to fix it? ;)

Comment: @Utkanos: `str_replace` is case sensisitve. You better want to use `preg_replace` to have more control on matching and replacing patterns.

Comment: My answer was pretty crappy actually. Edited to avoid the problems, perhaps... JS simulation: http://jsfiddle.net/5LPGT

Comment: Mate this is really awesome, last question i think ;)
if i type: "c o" or "co" it is altering my result and instead of "Charcoal" and "Coffee" it is returning "Charcoal" and "coffee", highlighting works perfect its just cosmetic that it is lowering first letter, script is essentially ment to display countries so it wouldnt be very polite to display netherland instead of Netherland ;d if there is some easy solution to make this script perfect it would be awesome ;)

Comment: Now it works a little bit strange, in database color name is "Banana yellow" and if i type "ban" it will give me "banana Yellow". "ban" in Banana is highlighet that is ok but it is still lower case and now yellow became upper "Y". Maybe instead of preg_replace if use preg_match or preg_match_all it would still be doing the job and not replace response from db just highlight it, but i dont know how to do it as well. Just an idea, maybe its wrong one.

Comment: Yeah sorry, perhaps I haven't quite nailed this. Hope someone else can finish it off as you require. Good luck with it.